# Forced undamped vibrations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I found a lot of literature when there is the forced undamped equation in form

$m''(t)+\gamma m(t)=F_0cos(wt)$ or the right side of equation $F_0sin(wt)$

But what to do if we have

$m''(t)+\gamma m(t)=asin(w_1t)+bcos(w_2t)$ 
couldn't find any examples or theory. And ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the equation is linear, we can use superposition principle and solve separetely

- $m_1''(t)+\gamma m_1(t)=a\sin(w_1t)$
- $m_2''(t)+\gamma m_2(t)=b\cos(w_2t)$

and the sum the two general solutions to obtain $m(t)=m_1(t)+m_2(t)$ and imposing on that the initial conditions.